# Can't install cartopy on python 3.11

Tags: python, cartopy, proj

I'm currently using python 3.11 that i run from spyder in the anaconda navigator and i (for me) tried everything to install cartopy (and basemap too) but it never worked.

I don't know why if someone can tell me if somethings is wrong with my setup or i d'ont know. I can add more informations but i don't know what to put for now.

Do I have to downgrade my python to a 3.10 version ? If so, how i can do it ? (same as cartopy, it didn't succed ...)

It might be something super easy but i don't see how, everytime i had to install packages, pip install worked.

Thanks for all the persons who will take time to help me !

Regards.

- I tried pip install cartopy first but didn't work (obviously)
- I tried to install the .whl of cartopy but unfortunatly there is no 3.11 version of it
- I tried conda install cartopy on the anaconda prompt (idk if i had to do something in anaconda.org before that so it lead to a fail)

Comment: You'll need to show us the error(s) you get.

Comment: Also, you state that there is no wheel for 3.11, but they do exists for cartopy 0.22.0: https://pypi.org/project/Cartopy/#files
Which version are you trying to install ?

Comment: This is what i get : WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001DFB7CEC410>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cartopy/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cartopy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cartopy

Comment: It finally work, ty for the 3.11 i didn't see it !